# Can I remove the last leaf line in tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-qtree, linguistics

I've got

```
\Tree [.CP [.TP [.NP [.D the ] [.N woman ] [.CP [.TP [.NP [.N who
] ] [.VP [.V stole ] [.NP [.D my ] [.N necklace ] ] ] ] ] ] [.VP
[.V entered ] ] ] ]
```

which gives me a nice tree, but the last leaf nodes (e.g. from N to woman) have a line connecting. Can I remove that one?

Comment: Please always post code that begins with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`, a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Once you've got this, it's easy to add a picture of the output to the question as well, which makes it more accessible for potential answerers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can remove this by doing the following:

Add the line

```
    \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
```

This allows node labels to have line breaks in them.

Then make all your terminal nodes be part of the node label itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\begin{document}
\Tree [.CP [.TP [.NP [.D\\the ] [.N\\woman ] [.CP [.NP [.N\\who
] ] [.TP [.NP\\t ]  [.VP [.V\\stole ] [.NP [.D\\my ] [.N\\necklace ] ] ] ] ] ] [.VP
[.V\\entered ] ] ] ]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]